# A.C. compressor doesn't turn on

Tags: ford, hvac, escape

2011 Ford Escape 3.0 FWD.
System has charge, no leaks, new expansion valve. Compressor fuse was removed. When turning on the AC. The fan did not kick on and compressor did not activate. Both fans turned on low only when temp was reached. Here's what I did:

I unhooked three wire connector at the accumulator in hopes to jump the connector to see if I could get the compressor to turn on. When I seen there were three wires with no diagram I decided to check the relay, but I forgot to plug the connector to the accumulator back in. I swapped relays and the high speed fan kicked in as it should. I got a little excited that it worked but the compressor didn't kick in. Then I noticed the accumulator connector was unplugged. I plugged it in and fan turned off and no compressor. In plug it the fan kicks in. Anyone know where to go from here?

Comment: How do you know that it has a full charge?

Comment: Manifold gages 90 static and running hi and lo

Comment: The static pressure reading tells two things: 1) your system is not completely empty, although it could be low on freon;  2) the pressure is enough to engage the compressor clutch.  I would test the resistance of the AC low pressure sensor.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. Checking the low pressure sensor was on the list. I don't have diagrams and was really crunched for time. I had one day to do a 5 1\2 hour drive 2 front wheel bearings, heater blower. Things went well so I started to try and diagnose  A.C. was just looking for quick results from the experience here. Time is up though, so I'll have time to check things out for the next time I see this (daughters) car.   I believe the pressure is close to good because I refilled to specs last time when I changed expansion valve.

Comment: If you don't have have the wiring diagram you can do a continuity check on the low pressure switch leads. You want continuity which indicates the switch is closed (completes the electrical circuit) and will allow the compressor clutch to kick in.  It is the same process to test the high pressure switch.  Both must be closed to complete the circuit.